# read.asciigrid: dimensions of map do not match that of header

Tags: r, spatial, mask, r-raster

```
library(raster)
library("stringr")

dr1=paste0("F:/NicheModworkingfile/mask_six_climate/",“chatian”)
setwd(dr1)
ref <- c("cmm.asc","drymon.asc",    "map.asc",  "mat.asc",  "wmm.asc",  "wsmcsm.asc")

refdat <- list()
for(j in 1:6){
  refdat[[j]] <- read.asciigrid(fname=ref[j])@data
}
```

I Countered the following error when I run the above code：

Error in read.asciigrid(fname = ref[j]) : dimensions of map do not match that of header.

Warning message:In scan(t, as.numeric(0), quiet = TRUE) : embedded nul(s) found in input.

Could anyone give me a clue how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this instead

```
dr1 <- "F:/NicheModworkingfile/mask_six_climate/chatian”
setwd(dr1)
ref <- c("cmm.asc","drymon.asc",    "map.asc",  "mat.asc",  "wmm.asc",  "wsmcsm.asc")
library(raster)
s <- stack(ref)
v <- values(s)
```

However, the error suggests that one of your files is corrupt. You can find out which one by subsetting `ref`.